# Android sensors: what is the difference between TYPE_ORIENTATION and TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR?

Tags: android, sensors

They seem similar, except in scale. Is one preferable to use over the other? Do they both work by combining accelerometer and magnetometer data - and if so, how exactly?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032825/whats-the-conceptual-difference-between-rotation-vector-sensor-and-orientation) is a similar question, the answer is pretty good. Also, since only a few android phones have a `gyroscope sensor`(which provides raw data for `ROTATION_VECTOR`), you need to consider if you really want to use `ROTATION_VECTOR` when you will release your app on a market. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347143/which-android-phones-out-there-do-have-a-gyroscope) is a good answer listing some devices which have a `gyroscope sensor`.